# How to customize jVectorMap region popups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jvectormap

I am currently using jvector map. When I hover each countries its default label shows each country name. But, I want to choose regions based on database value. How can I customize jvector map region pop up with database value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any content you want for tooltip using onRegionTipShow method. Just take a look at example available [here](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/).

Comment: just label.html(label.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')'); use this line working.  its showing country name default that place i want replace my database value? how  can i change?

Comment: @humble.rumble No, the answer with "thanks working well" first comment.

Comment: how to use database  value for  default country name?